Could not create Python venv in Ubuntu Server 24.04 because of zlib
OS: ubuntu-server 24.04
When I type python3.12 -m venv venv, I get this error
Error: Command '['/root/venv/bin/python3.12', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

I have not acitvated any venv before this.
The command above is automaticaly ran when I try to create venv.
I assume it is trying to install pip in the newly created venv ?
To check the detail, I ran the command directly
/root/venv/bin/python3.12 -m ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip and found that it's due to missing zlib module.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 518, in _get_decompress_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

I have tried to install zlib, it seems to be installed.
apt-get install zlib1g-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.3.dfsg-3.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

What I have done before this:

Tried building python3.12 from source, I just wanted to try if I could build from source, followed python dev guide, still failed with missing dependencies. Not sure if this would break the pre installed python3.12 ? I haven't tried to create venv before this, so I'm don't know if it was broken even before I tried to build from source.

Any suggestions would be very helpfull~~

Update:
Python venv works fine on a clean installation of ubuntu-server 24.04. I guess I really did break something when trying to build from source.
Will confirm later if resintalling python3.12-venv can solve the issue.
Update 2:
I gave up... just reinstalled ubuntu server

Are you already within a venv? The /root/venv/bin/python3.12 hints towards that you are calling a Python version within a venv named "venv" on not the system-wide Python.

No, I didn't activate any venv before running python3.12 -m venv venv, Some more info, even though it, failed, it did create a folder called venv, I assume that it might be trying to install pip inside the newly created venv ?
